# How to suppress unchecked typecast warning with generics not at declaration?

Tags: java, android

I have my code below which throws an unchecked typecast warning with the List assignment from ois.readObject(). Adding @SupressWarnings("unchecked") makes Android Studio give me an error saying "Annotations are not allowed here".

Is my only option to restructure the entire class so List tweets is declared on that line?

```
package com.fredliu.hellotwitter;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.fredliu.hellotwitter.models.Tweet;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TweetListActivity extends BaseListActivityWithMenu {
    private List<Tweet> tweets;
    private static final String cacheFile = "tweetCache.ser";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweet_list);
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(cacheFile);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
            tweets = (List<Tweet>) ois.readObject();

            ois.close();
            fis.close();
            Log.d("FREDFRED", "Tweets cache read from!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("FREDFRED", "Something horrible has happened when reading from the Tweets cache");
        }

        if (tweets == null || tweets.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No stored Tweets found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tweets = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                Tweet t = new Tweet();
                t.setTitle("Title " + i);
                t.setBody("Body " + i);
                tweets.add(t);
            }
        }


        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(cacheFile, MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(tweets);
            Log.d("FREDFRED", "Tweets successfully written to cache!");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("FREDFRED", "Tweet cache file not found" + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("FREDFRED", "Object not found when writing Tweet to cache");
        }


        ArrayAdapter a = new TweetAdapter(this, tweets);
        setListAdapter(a);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TweetDetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position + ", ID " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You said it "throws a warning" without the annotation. What happens after the cast? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject() can throw three different exceptions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to suppress a warning for a single statement, you can just insert the following:

```
// noinspection <checktype>
```

So for your case, for "unchecked", just change it to:

```
// noinspection unchecked
tweets = (List<Tweet>) ois.readObject();
```

EDIT: Another alternative would be to create some standalone method that performs the cast, and then apply the annotation to that method. Something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Tweet> asTweetList(ObjectInputStream ois) {
    return (List<Tweet>) ois.readObject();
}
```

and then use that instead:

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(cacheFile);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
List<Tweet> tweets = asTweetList(ois);
```

That keeps the suppression scope tight, as well as not being IDE-specific.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I Googled and it seems noinspection is IntelliJ-specific; if this issue were to come up in Eclipse, what is the resolution?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way, in that case, other than moving the annotation up to the entire method (which is certainly not ideal). One approach you could use to avoid the warning altogether is to create `class TweetList extends List<Tweet>` and use that instead of `List<Tweet>`.

Comment: Got it, the helper method idea is pretty neat thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Annotations can not be attached to expressions, statements, or blocks. So your options in this case are to annotate the private member tweets, or the method `onCreate` with `@SupressWarnings("unchecked")`. You can even annotate the entire class `TweetListActivity` if you would like to suppress all unchecked warnings for that class (not recommended).

Comment: Thanks, your answer is a good idea however I won't be using it because I don't want to disable type checking for a larger scope than needed

Comment: This is good to know in theory, but in practice it does not appear to be true in all cases. E.g. I'm getting the same error as the OP in some cases, but in others, I'm able to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before a statement in the middle of a block and the IDE doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation, to suppress warnings from entire function/method, like:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
MyResultType myFunction(MyInputType myValue)
{
    return (MyResultType) myValue;
}
```

Or add an inline-comment on each line, like:

```java
//noinspection unchecked
tweets = (List<Tweet>) ois.readObject();
```

**Where** the difference is that the inline-comment is for IDE, and my Android compiler at least, ignores it and warns anyway.

**However,** said "`suppress warnings from entire function`" may hide some other issue, hence I prefer to use a helper, like:

```java
MyType myVariable;

// ...

myVariable = Unchecked.cast( myValue );
```

Or in OP's case:

```java
tweets = Unchecked.cast( ois.readObject() );
```

Which needs below to be added to project:

```java
package my.package_name;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

/**
 * Helper similar to `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, or `//noinspection unchecked` comment.
 *
 * <br><br><h2>The difference is that:</h2><ul>
 *
 * <li>Said annotation wraps entire function, causing more than needed to be ignored
 * (since it does not support being placed before R-value, at time of writing).
 *
 * <li>The compiler may ignore said comment, and warn anyway.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "RedundantTypeArguments", "RedundantSuppression"})
public class Unchecked {
    /**
     * Type-cast implementation for reasons mentioned on {@link Unchecked} class.
     *
     * <br><br>Usage:
     * <pre>{@code
     * //noinspection RedundantTypeArguments
     * T myResult = Unchecked.<T>cast(myInput);
     * }</pre>
     *
     * <br><br>WARNING: To be sure compiler picks the right type,
     * set the type-argument, and suppress `RedundantTypeArguments`.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <NewType> NewType cast(@NonNull Object value) {
        return (NewType) value;
    }
}
```